# How to check if there is any part of element on top using js?

Tags: javascript

I need to check for given element if there exists any point that `elementFromPoint` with this point given as argument will return this element. I do not need to find that point - just information if there is at least one. It is equivalent to "if there exists any part of the element which is not covered by another element".

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydxykggv/1/) - since there is a part of `num2` and `num3` which is "on top" desired function should return `true` for those two. However for `num1` result should be `false`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't make any sense of the question. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: A code snippet paints 1000 words

Comment: Please review [ask] and update your question to include a [mcve] of what you've tried.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for that - it is one of my first questions here. I've tried to provide some example to make it clear. If anything is not obvious please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way than this brute force option of getting the element's boundaries using `element.getClientRects()`, and then iterating over that area with `elementFromPoint` to see if it ever returns that element:

```js
var checkIfOnTop = function(el) {
  console.log("Checking",el);
  var rect = el.getClientRects()[0];
  for (var x = rect.left; x <= rect.right; x++) {
    for (var y = rect.top; y <= rect.bottom; y++) {
      if (document.elementFromPoint(x, y) === el) {
        console.log("This element is reachable by click at ",x,y);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("This element is not reachable by click");
  return false;
}

checkIfOnTop(document.getElementById('num1'));
checkIfOnTop(document.getElementById('num2'));
checkIfOnTop(document.getElementById('num3'));
```

```css
#container { position: relative }
#num1 { position: absolute; left: 50px; height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: blue}
#num2 { position: absolute; left: 50px; height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: green}
#num3 { position: absolute; left: 100px; height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: red}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='num1'></div>
    <div id='num2'></div>
    <div id='num3'></div>
</div>
```

Not recommended for very large elements, of course.

Comment: It is still heuristic, isn't it?

Comment: @LJK I don't understand what you mean?   The function does return `true` or `false` appropriately, in addition to the explanatory `console.log`s.